# Hiveserver2 dont start: "ascii codec cant encode character"

Tags: java, python, hadoop, hive

I made a cluster with NameNode, Secondary NameNode, and 3 DataNodes. I installed HDP via Ambari + HUE and now I am configuring XA secure policies for HDFS, Hive and Hbase. It works fine for every component, except Hive. Problem is that when I change hive.security.authorization to true (in Ambari -> hive configs) the Hiveserver2 fails at start with a problem:

`File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/providers/system.py", line 115, in action_create
    fp.write(content)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 990: ordinal not in range(128)`

I tried to edit that python file but when I do any changes it gets even worse. It probably tries to encode Unicode character using wrong codec and save it to the file, but I am bad programmer and I dont know how to edit it correctly. I cant figure out what is that file, where is it and what it contains.

When I set security authorization to false, the server starts but crashes in ~3 minutes with an error: 
`12:02:43,523 ERROR [pool-1-thread-648] JMXPropertyProvider:540 - Caught exception getting JMX metrics : Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://localhost.localdomain:8745/api/cluster/summary
12:02:50,604  INFO [qtp677995254-4417] HeartBeatHandler:428 - State of service component HIVE_SERVER of service HIVE of cluster testING has changed from STARTED to INSTALLED at host localhost.localdomain
12:02:53,624 ERROR [pool-1-thread-668] JMXPropertyProvider:540 - Caught exception getting JMX metrics : Read timed out`

Any suggestions? Thank you in advance.

@EDIT 
Here is line of code in python which causes problem:
`fp.write(content)`
I was trying to add .decode("utf-8") at the end but:
`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'decode'` occurs

Answer (score -1):

For the first problem, try adding

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

At the first line of your file

Comment: Thanks for answer but still the same problem